# finding the difference between two dates and saving the result to a database

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following code in my controller..I want to find the difference between two dates(from and to) so that I get the number of days in between the n save it to a database..

```
class LeaveController extends Controller
{
     public function ApplyLeave(Request $request){

        $days = $request->datepicker->diff($request->datepicker1);

    Auth::user()->sent()->create([
        'tel'       => $request->tel,
        'email'    => $request->email,
        'start' => Carbon::parse($request->datepicker),
        'end' => Carbon::parse($request->datepicker1),
        'supervisor'    => $request->supervisor,
        'department' => $request->department,
        'name'    => $request->name,
        'adress' => $request->adress,
        'days' =>   $days,
    ]);   

    return view('home');
}
```

with what I have so far , I get the following error:

> Call to a member function diff() on string

How to go about with this?

Comment: What is the string that you have in $request->datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

```
$d1 = new Carbon($request->datepicker);
$d2 = new Carbon($request->datepicker1);
$days = $d1->diff($d2)->days;
```

Note that you need ->days to get the actual days amount.

Note that you will have trouble with times. You may wish to ->setTime(0,0,0) in order to get the days between 2 dates.

Note that your format may not be standard. In this case use:

```
$format = 'm\d\Y';
$d1 = Carbon::createFromFormat($request->datepicker,$format);
$d2 = Carbon::createFromFormat($request->datepicker1,$format);
$days = $d1->diff($d2)->days;
```

Answer (score 2):

Man, Don't use Carbon when basic PHP functions can provide you the best solution. Use OOP:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($request->datepicker);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($request->datepicker1);
$interval= $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = $interval->format('%a');
```

If you are curious why you are getting that error then its because you are using `diff()` function which takes date object as parameter and you are providing plain string.

Comment: No Problem. Happy Coding!